# Am I ready for a long trip in bicycle?

Tags: weight-loss, training, bicycling

I've been training for the last three months to complete a 90 Km route. I feel my legs are ready for that, but I'm affraid my weight can be a problem.

I'm 31 years olds, 165 cm tall (5' 5"), and my current weight is 65 Kg (143 pounds).

I've increased progressively the intensity of my training. Now, I complete 10 Km 4 times each week.

What do you think is the maximum weight (given my height) to accomplish this challenge?

Should I increase my training distance before attempting that trip?

Any other recommendation will be helpful.

BR,
Sebastian

Comment: On this site, you want to frame questions so that the answers will be helpful to others, eg, "Are 10 km rides sufficient preparation for a 90 km ride? Does weight matter?" You might find someone has asked this kind of question at http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/9225/what-should-i-be-doing-a-week-before-a-long-distance-bike-ride .

Comment: I think the question is properly asked. I added details to give enough information. Honestly, I don't see a big difference between my question and the one you mentioned.

Comment: The details are good! It would probably be just rewording sentences to use the word "I" less, and changing the title from "Am I ready?" [answer applies subjectively to you] to "How to prepare for a 90 km bike ride?" [answer applies to any bicyclist using Google]. 

I just saw you had four close votes and instead of being the fifth one I wanted to explain.

For an answer, I don't think your weight enters into it given that you are completely normal BMI, and you should try working up to 20, 40, 60, 80% of the distance. But I'm completely unknowledgeable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you never cycle more than 10km in one ride, I would guess you are not ready for a 90km ride. A fast cyclist averaging 30kph will take three hour to complete such a ride, a slower one might have to stay on the saddle 5 hours or more. The following problems will surface for casual cyclists:

- leg cramps
- sore back
- the dreaded [bonk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitting_the_wall) if you do not eat/drink adequately
- [chafing](http://www.livestrong.com/article/462068-chafing-on-inner-thighs-from-bike-riding/) problems

I would recommend you gradually build up the length of your ride to a minimum of 50km before attempting your 90km. It's not like you won't manage it at all if you try, it's just that you are not likely to enjoy much due to the above issues. Try to follow a [training plan](https://www.britishcycling.org.uk/knowledge/training-plans) if you are unsure how to structure your training. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

[personal experience]
Am I ready for 1.5 hour mma/crossfit training since I did lower-intensity training before?
Thoughts: yep
Reality: half-dead and almost puking after 1.5 hours

[example 2]
Am I ready for 40 km biking trip after travelling 2 x 10 km daily? 
Thoughts: yep
Reality: carry me home please

This makes me thing you should increase the distance you travel progressively until you travel the 90 kilometers.